# Serialização de exceções

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, serialização

Segundo as documentações msdn, uma exceção deve ser serializada caso ela deva ser propagada para fora do assembler.

No visual studio, tenho uma solução com alguns projetos, dentre eles um projeto de biblioteca de classes (dll), no qual eu crio várias exceções próprias.

Até onde eu entendo esse projeto (dll), será um assembler independente onde os outros projetos(outras dlls), main, etc, irão precisar acessar as classes contidas nele para tratar e lançar as exceções que foram criadas lá.

Esse é um caso em que as exceções devem ser serializadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a exceção que você define na DLL (a) não vai sair da "caixa preta do processo onde ela está rodando", então você não precisa se preocupar com serialização. Se você tem uma DLL (b) ou um EXE (c) que referenciam a DLL (a), e o código deles *catch* a exception, você ainda está na mesma caixa do processo, e a exceção é apenas mais um objeto em memória, que é compartilhada por todos os componentes (exe e dll) do processo. Isso é o caso da maioria das aplicações.

Se a sua exceção pode escapar do processo - por exemplo, você tem um service com um método externo que pode *throw* a exceção, então a serialização precisa ser implementada, para que ela seja enviada para o cliente via "rede" (pode ser a rede de verdade, um named pipe entre processos, ou qualquer outra forma onde o objeto tenha que ser transformado em uma *stream* de bytes). Outros exemplos são se você quer persistir a informação da exceção no disco, ou por qualquer motivo realizar a serialização "na mão" da exceção (ou de um objeto que a contenha).

Note que mesmo em situações onde você quer transmitir um erro para um cliente (por exemplo, num web service), raramente você quer transmitir o objeto da exceção diretamente, pois ele contem muito mais informações que o cliente precisa (por exemplo, stack trace). Nesse caso é comum a criação de DTOs (*data transfer objects*) para conter somente a informação relevante.