# System.Runtime.Serialization em UWP 10

Tags: c#, exceção, uwp

Estou criando uma exceção em um `UWP`, porém, parece que apps `UWP` não dispõem dos mesmos recursos para serialização que as aplicações clássicas.
O código abaixo não funciona para `UWP`.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace CustomExceptions
{
    [Serializable]
    public class InvalidCpfException : Exception
    {
        public InvalidCpfException ( ) { }
        public InvalidCpfException ( string message ) : base(message) { }
        public InvalidCpfException ( string message, Exception inner ) : base(message, inner) { }
        protected InvalidCpfException ( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context ) : base(info, context) { }
    }
}
```

Parece que não existe o atributo `[Serializable]` e o tipo `SerializationInfo`. Como garantir a serialização da exceção em `UWP`?

Comment: Certeza que precisa do `[Serializable]`? Qual o objetivo do uso? Não estou muito por dentro do assunto mas pelo que li (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112335/serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es) não se faz necessário no seu cenário.

Comment: Verdade, você está certo, no meu caso não será necessário. Eu mesmo criei a pergunta do link que você postou. Eu já nem lembrava mais dela.
Toda via acho que seria interessante que alguém deixasse uma resposta. Tendo em vista que `UWP` ainda é uma tecnologia pouco popular e muitos recursos sobre ela ainda é escasso de conteúdo, especialmente em Português.

Comment: O UWP não precisa desse atributo para que a exceção personalizada funcione.